# Update Model and Controllers modify DB table in Yii

Tags: yii

I was wondering that see if you have made many changes since Gii generated your `Model` and `CRUD`. i.e you have applied many view changes ,made rbac and so on.

now what if later on you see thati.e in persons table you have to add a new entery `car_no` and you want CRUD to accept that change and CActiveRecord adapt changes to db..

what can be done to avoid a RE-DO? as RE-DO works for me at present :(

Thanks

Comment: If it's just one entry, manually editing your model/controller will be easier.

Comment: so if you make changes in model and controler then nothing else is required?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. Of course you need to modify your views if you want to use the value of the new entries in the views. Other than that none that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit it manually. Nothing else is needed. I have added entries to my tables hundreds of times, updated models, controller, views manually, and it has always worked perfectly.